# Customize a list in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

Laravel noob here. I just created a table in Laravel and now I want to customize it using CSS. How do I exactly do it? Here is the picture of the table (I want to change the padding, text color). [LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wP20.png)

I have tried changing it with HTML styles. but I have no idea how to edit CSS in Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply following Tailwind classe to style the tables.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="w-full whitespace-nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="border px-6 py-4">Column 1</th>
      <th class="border px-6 py-4">Column 2</th>
      <th class="border px-6 py-4">Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="border px-6 py-4">Data 1</td>
      <td class="border px-6 py-4">Data 2</td>
      <td class="border px-6 py-4">Data 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not about Laravel, it is about HTML and CSS and you have to learn these two first.

You can apply some styles like this:

```
<style>
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 15px;
    }
</style>


<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use some frameworks like bootstrap and Tailwind to do that easily.

Use [bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_tables.php) :

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You can see the full example in [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h).